# Protect my PHP App

Tags: php

I have developed an app and its written in PHP (with a bunch of SQL scripts), this app will be used by a few small companies. For them to use it, I will have to install Apache and SQL Server for them.

Every method I have thought has fallen short of what I need. I was actually just hoping to use ZendGuard or IonCube but they don't support PHP 5.3.x.

Is there a simpler method where I can maybe store a key in the database and make the app run only when it knows its on that server?

Maybe create a key based on some random numbers/letters and the machine name, sql server host name and encode/decode this when ever the system is in use?

Thanks all for any help or ideas

Comment: You even have no idea how many such a scripts can be found all over internet. Zillions. Anyone who need a script, can just google for it. Be modest, don't think anyone would jealous about them.

Comment: There is one more problem: code encoded using ZendGuard can be decoded (I don't know if it's the same with IonCube).

Comment: @Shrapnel - my app does not perform a common task. Its specific to a niche set of companies and you won't find this on Google. Trust me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if Zend and Ioncube don't support PHP 5.3 code (which I find hard to believe!! Are you sure?), I'm sure they will in the foreseeable future.

I think it's worth asking them when they are going to introduce support for it.

Update: It indeed seems true: [Zend](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/system-requirements) but then, the question is, does your software really need 5.3 (i.e. use 5.3 specific features like namespaces and such?)

Comment: I thought about using 5.2 but then I realised that the SQL Server PHP Driver that works with PHP version 5.3 over comes certain limitations (not truncating long fields returned from sql server) which the 5.2 version does not offer. I'm stuck in an awkward position!

Comment: @Abs I see. That sucks! But if those two flagships don't have 5.3 support, I find it hard to imagine other solutions have. I don't know for sure, though - maybe it's worth sifting through the "How to compile PHP" questions on SO and checking the products mentioned.

Comment: I know! I think I'll have to look around for something, it doesn't have to be top end.