# how to "close" a php script for commercial use?

Tags: php, saas, product-key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - protecting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177497/php-protecting-code)

I have build a php "management" site for a client with some specific features very usefull for their kind of business.
So I decided with the client to sell to other companies this back-office software.

How can I close this php site so that clients ho buy it can install it only once and validate it with a key? also, can they just copy all files and db and give it to someone else?

What are the techniques to close a php site as a SaaS?

Comment: Have a look at [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) which will allow you to obfuscate your code and also configure usage policies and restrictions.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+obfuscate

Comment: :-( Linking a duplicate to a duplicate to a duplicate is somewhat confusing…

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to encode it (for example) with [Ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/) or [ZendGuard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) so they can't easily delete your checkings. However, remember, if they want to crack it, they will